# Freeze Rails 2.1.0 in Dreamhost using Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, freeze, dreamhost

I have 2 applications on Dreamhost using Rails 2.1.0, recently they installed Rails 3 on my server and broke my apps.
I found this post that explains how to freeze a rails app - http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/1/3/freezing-your-rails-application, but when I run the command `rake rails:freeze:gems` back this error:

```
rake aborted!
can't activate rails (= 2.3.8, runtime) for [], already activated rails-3.0.3 for []
```

I uninstalled and installed again the rake, but still resulting in this error. What can be done to solve this problem? someone went through this already know or help me?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you right now, if I find a solution I let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All freeze:gems does is copy the gem directory to vendor/gems, you can do this by hand.

Another way you can get this done is to locally install Rails 2.1 and get get your app running and rake rails:freeze:gems there, then upload back to the server.